# Check either fog = gof or not

Tags: functions

I know how to solve fog and gof problem but its something look like matrix, this is creating problem for me. I have no idea how to solve this function related math.

> If $f=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&1\end{bmatrix}$ and
>   $g=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&1&3\end{bmatrix}$
>   check if $f\circ g$ is equal to $g\circ f$ or not.

Edited: As egreg said - 
fog(1) = f(g(1)) = f(2) = 3, fog(2) = f(g(2)) = f(1) = 2, fog(3) = f(g(3)) = f(3) = 1
gof(1) = g(f(1)) = g(2) = 1, gof(2) = g(f(2)) = g(3) = 3, gof(3) = g(f(3)) = g(1) = 2

Still I am unable to conclude either fog = gof or not will you please explain?

Comment: "its something look like matrix" Wow. Please check the lecture notes attached to this. (One of the most stunning upvotes on the site...)

Comment: I don't understand, has this question been asked before?

Comment: "fog" is misty vapor in the air and "gof" is something someone might say if you quickly shoved something into their mouth.

Comment: Do you know what it means for two functions to be equal?

Comment: If and only if domain are equal of two function then it would be equal isn't it ?

Comment: Since $f\circ g(1)=3$ and $g\circ f(1)=1$, you have already concluded that $f\circ g\ne g\circ f$.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the matrices represent permutations on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. So they are the same as saying
$$
f(1)=2,\quad f(2)=3,\quad f(3)=1\\
g(1)=2,\quad g(2)=1,\quad g(3)=3
$$
Now, $f\circ g(1)=f(g(1))=f(2)=3$ and so on. Can you do this for all elements, both for $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$? What can you see, then?